# Finding the $n$th stationary point of $f(x)=e^{ax}\cos{(bx)}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

If you take the function: $f(x)=e^{ax}\cos{(bx)}$ with $a>0 \land b>0$ then I would like to show that the stationary points (for $x>0$) form a geometric progression with common ratio $-e^{a\pi/b}$. I think I've done that (or hopefully I'm close to it) but I wanted to check whether it's correct since the given method is slightly different and I'm doubtful of mine.

Anyway, I found the $x$ values that are stationary points to be:$$x=\frac{\arctan{(a/b)}+n\pi}{b} \;\; n\in \mathbb{Z}$$
and so after putting that into $f(x)$ (and after using the cosine addition formula) I got:
$$ e^{\left(\frac{a}{b}\arctan{(a/b)}\right)}[\cos(\arctan{a/b})\cos(n\pi)-\sin(\arctan{a/b})(\sin(n\pi)] \left(e^{{\frac{a\pi}{b}}}\right)^n$$
where obviously $\sin(n\pi)=0$. This is where I'm not too sure it's right, I simplified $\cos(n\pi)$ to $(-1)^n$ thereby giving:
$$\left[e^{\left(\frac{a}{b}\arctan{(a/b)}\right)}\cos(\arctan(a/b))\right]\times(-1)^n\left(e^{{\frac{a\pi}{b}}}\right)^n  $$
and then writing it as:
$$ \left[e^{\left(\frac{a}{b}\arctan{(a/b)}\right)}\cos(\arctan(a/b))\right]\times\left(-e^{{\frac{a\pi}{b}}}\right)^n  $$
hence showing that it's a geometric progression. I think there may be an issue with assuming $\cos(n\pi)$ is *specifically* $n$ and not some general integer but I'm not sure. If it is indeed wrong is there a way to do it more generally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative of $f(x) = \exp(ax) \cos(bx)$ is $\exp(ax) (a \cos(bx) - b \sin(bx))$, 
so this is $0$ whenever $a \cos(bx) - b \sin(bx) = 0$.  If $p = \arctan(a/b)$, this becomes $\sin(bx-p) = 0$, so it is true exactly when $x = (p + n \pi)/b$ for some integer $n$.  The corresponding values of $f(x)$ are
$$ f((p+n\pi)/b) = \exp(ap/b) \exp(n a\pi/b) \cos(p+n\pi) = \exp(ap/b) \cos(p) (-\exp(a\pi/b))^n$$

Note that since you've assumed $a > 0$ and $b > 0$, $0 < p < \pi/2$,  the first nonnegative value of $x$ corresponds to $n = 0$.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. When you simplified $\cos(p+n\pi)$ did you turn it into $(-1)^n\times \cos(p)$ and then put the $(-1)^n$ with the exponential?

Comment: Yes, that's what I did....

Comment: Ok thanks! Just wanted to check since I wasn't sure whether the $n$ introduced with the arctangent was the same as the $n$ in the cosine simplification. Which it appears to be. Thanks again.