# Extrema of function $y=e^{-kx} \sin(nx)$ form a geometric progression

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I found this problem in Sinhalese and I'm trying my best to translate it:

> Prove that the graph of $y=e^{-kx}\sin(nx)$ has a series of minimum and maximum ordinates, along the $x$-axis at every integer $\pi/n$ interval. And prove that they make a decreasing sequence according to a geometric progression for all $k\in\mathbb{R}^+$.

I took the derivative and found its roots. Hence, found there are minimums and maximums at every integer $\pi/n$ interval. I did not go further because I was not really sure what the problem asked.

Please explain how to prove it.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure how you solved the question, because what it is asking you looks false. The mins and maxes don't occur at equal $\pi/n$ intervals, but there is always a min or a max in every integer $\pi/n$ interval. There is a big misconception that the mins and maxes of $f(x)\sin(nx)$ occur at evenly spaced intervals of $\pi/n$ but it is not true.

Comment: For what it's worth, if $n=0,$ then regardless of the value of $k$ the graph will be the $x$-axis, which has (non-strict) max and min at every point, but not for $x = \pi/n,$ since $\pi/n$ does not exist in this case (i.e. when $n = 0).$ But I suppose one could still say the result is vacuously true. There are other issues with the wording also . . .

Comment: Suppose $x_m$ is the sequence of $x$ values of mins and maxes you found. Now consider $y_m = e^{-kx_m}\sin(nx_m)$. The problem wants you to show that $y_m$ is a decreasing geometric sequence.

Comment: @NinadMunshi The $x$-coordinates of the extrema of this function really are separated by exactly $\pi/n$. (For a lot of similar functions, this might appear to be true but is not the case.)

Comment: I have taken the liberty to change the intial title into a form that better reflects the content of the question. I wish you agree it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I just discovered that a completely similar question (with $\cos$ instead of $\sin$) had already been asked on MathSE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/918553/305862)].

---

An initial remark: the problem is correctly set if one interprets "in every $\pi/n$ interval" as "in every interval $[k \pi/n, (k+1) \pi/n]$"

**First solution:**

Let $$f(x):=e^{-kx} \sin(nx)\tag{1}$$

Have a look at the following figure, made with Geogebra, featuring the different extrema $(x_p,y_p), \ \ p=0,1,2...$ and allowing the computation of the ordinates $y_p$.
[image]

Let us find the abscissas $x_p$ of the extremas by solving equation $f'(x)=0$:

$$e^{-kx}(-k \sin(nx) + n \cos(nx))=0$$

giving :

$$\underbrace{\tfrac{\sin(nx)}{\cos(nx)}}_{\tan(nx)}=\frac{n}{k}\tag{2}$$

Setting $a=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{n}{k}\right) \ \iff \ \tan(a)=\frac{n}{k},$

(2) is equivalent to $\tan(nx)=\tan(a)$, itself equivalent to

$$nx=a+p \pi \ \ \text{for a certain integer} \ p \ge 0$$
because $\tan$ is a $\pi$-periodic function. Finally

$$x=x_p=\frac{a}{n}+p \frac{\pi}{n}, \ \text{for} \ p=0,1,2 \cdots \tag{3}$$

Remark: please note that the abscissas of the extremas form an arithmetic sequence.

Numerical testing (using criteria $y_{p-1}y_{p+1}=y_p^2$) on the first values of $p$ have convinced me that sequence $y_p=f(x_p)$ is indeed a geometric progression with a negative ratio $-1<r<0$.

Here is the proof:

$$f(x_p)=e^{-k\left(\frac{a}{n}+p \frac{\pi}{n}\right)}\sin \left(n \left(\frac{a}{n}+p \frac{\pi}{n}\right)\right)$$

$$y_p=e^{-k\left(\frac{a}{n}+p \frac{\pi}{n}\right)}\sin(a+p \pi) $$

$$y_p=e^{-\frac{ka}{n}}(e^{-\frac{k \pi}{n}})^p (-1)^p\sin(a) $$

$$y_p=\underbrace{e^{-\frac{ka}{n}}\sin(a)}_{\text{first term} \ y_0}(\underbrace{-e^{-\frac{k \pi}{n}}}_{\text{ratio} \ r})^p  \tag{4}$$

proving that sequence $y_p$ is a geometric progression with negative ratio.

**Remark:** in fact, nothing prevents from taking negative values of $p$ : otherwise said, the maxima/minima for negative values of the variable could have been considered as well.

**Second solution: (sketched)**

$e^{-kx} \sin(nx)$ is the imaginary part of $e^{-kx} e^{inx}$. Otherwise said, setting $nx=\theta$, our issue amounts to find the ordinates of the maxima/minima of logarithmic spiral with polar equation :

$$\rho=e^{-\tfrac{k}{n} \theta}\tag{5}$$

which clearly happen when

$$\theta=\theta_p=\frac{\pi}{2}+p \pi \tag{6}$$

(if $p$ is even, it is a maxima, otherwise a minima)

Replacing into (5) the expression of $\theta$ given by (6), we get

$$\underbrace{\rho_p}_{y_p}=e^{-\tfrac{k}{n}(\tfrac{\pi}{2}+p \pi)}=e^{-\tfrac{k \pi}{2n}}\left(e^{-\tfrac{k \pi}{n}}\right)^p$$

which differs from (4) because the sign information is - naturally - not present in this polar equation.

Therefore, (5) appears as a kind of continuous version of (4).

I don't expand furthermore this solution because it necessitates to know some techniques on polar equations that are not necessarily commonplace.

Answer (score 2):

The function vansihes at the points $m\pi/n$ hence it admits alternatively the minimum and the maximum on the intervals $ [(m-1)/n,m\pi/n],$ depending on the parity of $m.$ The equation for the extremal points is $$ -ke^{-kx}\sin(nx)+ne^{-kx}\cos(nx)=0$$ hence $\tan(nx)={n\over k}.$ We obtain infintely many solutions $$x_m={m\pi\over n}+{\arctan(n/k)\over n}$$ Let $\alpha = {\arctan(n/k)\over n}$ We get $$f(x_m)=(-1)^me^{-km\pi/n}e^{k\alpha}$$ The maxima, i.e. $f(x_{2m})$ form a decreasing geometric progression.

Comment: Thanks to you, I have been able to spot where I was blocked in my proof. Salute to Poland in these difficult times !

Comment: I have added a second solution that, in a certain sense, explains in a more natural way why we have a geometric progression.